# How to make auto resizing buttons via swift 3 that work between different Iphones

Tags: ios, swift

I'll post down below a part of my code on an app I'm working on for fun, the concept it's different, but the design of the camera session is very similar with the instagram app. I'm also using the PageMenu cocoa pod, that is really good and easy to implement via code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pageMenu?.delegate = self
    photoControllerBG.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y : self.view.frame.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height )

    let cameraButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.midX -  , y: photoControllerBG.frame.minY + (self.view.frame.maxY/20*1), width: 130, height: 130))
    cameraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraButtonPressed(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Camera Button.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    self.view.addSubview(cameraButton)
}
```

At the moment, the button on an iPhone 7 Plus will display like I want it to, centered in the ViewController and with the Image of the camera button with the same width and height so it stay a perfect circle. The problem presents itself when i switch the simulator with a iPhone SE or iPhone 6, where the button will become too big and not centered. Can you guys help me to find a math formula that it can be used to solve this big but small problem?

Comment: First I think it would be better for you to use autolayout.. anyway what you are trying to achieve? having the button centered at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Tried to use it, but the buttons and the view won't stay where i want.

Answer (score 2):

Your question implies doing the following in code (swift). Unless you are creating the button in swift I wouldn't do that at all. So, If you have a button created in a storyboard you can scale it appropriately as follows:-

I would use a proportional width constraint combined with an aspect ratio constraint in the story board to achieve this.

It may not be apparent straight away how to do this so I attach a picture journey.

1. Add your button to the view controller. Image shows final constraints.

[image]

2. Add an Equal Width constraint between the button and it's superview

[image]

3. The button doesn't have equal width to it's superview! My button is 100 px wide and the superview is 375 px wide. So let's calculate that ratio to help us calculate the proportional width.

[image]

4. Edit the Equal width constraint by using the proportional width above as the multiplier.

[image]

5. Add an aspect ratio to the button

[image]

6. Add any remaining constraints (In my case I centred the button horizontally and vertically)
7. Your constraints for the button should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your really complete answer i'll try implementing this now. I'll report if it works like i need it to or i need something different (i hope not)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "title"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(label)

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image"), for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(button)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 16)
    ])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3), //change your multiplier
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor)
        ])
```

Comment: I'll try this one now, let me see

Comment: Implemented it, but the button need to stay a little away from the top of the view controller. Using you code, the image of the button cut's in half if i set the Y to topAnchor. What can i do?

Comment: @MattiaGerardi remove `button.centerYAnchor ...` this line, add`button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)`

Comment: Great! It stays almost where i want to. In my view controller, now the top of the circle touch the top bar or the view, but i need it moved like inch down, so i can add a variable label at the top of it. Can i do that using your method? Thanks for the replies man

Comment: Thanks man, i'll implement it now on my project! Thanks for all the help until now!